# Bundle ID change

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm at the point of submitting my binary to iTunes Connect and need to change the Bundle ID. I haven't uploaded my binary yet but just want to make sure I have all my ducks in a row so this process is seamless.

I've already created a App ID that has IAP, also Development and Distribution Provisioning profiles and filled out all info in iTunes Connect all under the old Bundle ID. The last thing I needed to do was upload the binary but now I have to change the Bundle ID.

So to change the Bundle ID in Xcode all that needs to be done is go in my plist to Bundle Identifier and change the string thats there from companyname.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rcf) to companyname.newName? Now since I've already created an App ID with the old Bundle ID do I need to make a whole new App ID? I can't find anywhere to edit the Bundle ID and update to the new one.

Once I make a new App ID (if I have to) it looks like I can still change it in my iTunes Connect app from the drop down tab next to Bundle ID so that shouldn't be an issue. Also will my IAP have to be updated, I already have them Ready to Submit? It also looks like in my Development and Distribution Provisioning profiles I can edit and change to a new App ID. I would just have to download and install them again to work with the new ID?

I just want to double check if this is the correct way of doing it so I don't run in to any issues. Thank you for any feed back you can give me.

Comment: you must create a new app id from your developer.apple.com , you should regenerate your provision profiles , and finally change you bundle id in your project, and i think about iAP you should regenerate your work again.

Comment: Can I change just the BundleName with out having to change my whole Project Name in build settings? There for leaving my current Bundle ID intact? I ask because I got this Error "Error itms-90129 the bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an apple app" while trying to submit my app to iTunes connect. I  know it's my BundleName creating the issue as its name is "Clock"